# SSIS : Huge Data Transfer from Source (SQL Server) to Destination (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Requirement :

1. Transfer millions of records from source (SQL Server) to destination (SQL Server).
2. Structure  of source tables is different from destination tables.
3. Refresh data once per week in destination server.
4. Minimum amount of time for the processing.

I am looking for optimized approach using SSIS.

Was thinking these options :

1. Create Sql dump from source server and import that dump in destination server.
2. Directly copy the tables from source server to destination server.

Comment: so you're moving across servers? or just between databases or tables on the same server?

Comment: *Linked Servers* can query each other directly, that's probably the simplest technique to use.  If the data is only refreshed once a week *Minimum amount of time* does not seem to be that critical.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of issues to consider here.  Such as are the servers in the same domain, on same network, etc.

Most of the time you will not want to move the data as a single large chunk of millions of records but in smaller amounts.  An SSIS package handles that logic for you, but you can always recreate it as well but iterating the changes easier.  Sometimes this is a reason to push changes more often rather than wait an entire week as smaller syncs are easier to manage with less downtime.

Another consideration is to be sure you understand your delta's and to ensure that you have ALL of the changes.  For this reason I would generally suggest using a staging table at the destination server.  By moving changes to staging and then loading to the final table you can more easily ensure that changes are applied correctly.  Think of the scenario of a an increment being out of order (identity insert), datetime ordered incorrectly or 1 chunk failing.  When using a staging table you don't have to rely solely on the id/date and can actually do joins on primary keys to look for changes.

Linked Servers proposed by Alex K. can be a great fit, but you will need to pay close attention to a couple of things. Always do it from Destination server so that it is a PULL not a push.  Linked servers are fast at querying the data but horrible at updating/inserting in bulk. 1 XML column cannot be in the table at all. You may need to set some specific properties for distributed transactions.

I have done this task both ways and I would say that SSIS does give a bit of advantage over Linked Server just because of its robust error handling, threading logic, and ability to use different adapters (OLEDB, ODBC, etc. they have different performance do a search and you will find some results).  But the key to your #4 is to do it in smaller chunks and from a staging table and if you can do it more often it is less likely to have an impact.  E.g. daily means it would already be ~1/7th of the size as weekly assuming even daily distribution of changes.

```
Take 10,000,000 records changed a week.
Once weekly = 10mill
once daily = 1.4 mill
Once hourly = 59K records
Once Every 5 minutes = less than 5K records
```

And if it has to be once a week.  just think about still doing it in small chunks so that each insert will have more minimal affect on your transaction logs, actual lock time on production table etc.  Be sure that you never allow loading of a partially staged/transferred data otherwise identifying delta's could get messed up and you could end up missing changes/etc.

One other thought if this is a scenario like a reporting instance and you have enough server resources.  You could bring over your entire table from production into a staging or update a copy of the table at destination and then simply do a drop of current table and rename the staging table.  This is an extreme scenario and not one I generally like but it is possible and actual impact to the user would be very nominal.

Comment: Thank you Matt.  Structure of source tables is different from destination tables. Destination tables we are using for reporting . What precaution do I need to consider if we use SSIS package?

Comment: Solid information, Matt. +1 on the effort toward a pretty broad question.

Answer (score 2):

I think SSIS is good at transfer data, my approach here:

**1**. Create a package with one **Data Flow Task** to transfer data. If the structure of two tables is different then it's okay, just map them.
**2**. Create a **SQL Server Agent job** to run your package every weekend

Also, feature **Track Data Changes** (SQL Server) is also good to take a look. You can config when you want to sync data and it's good at performance too

Answer (score 1):

With SQL Server versions >2005, it has been my experience that a dump to a file with an export is equal to or slower than transferring data directly from table to table with SSIS.

That said, and in addition to the excellent points @Matt makes, this the usual pattern I follow for this sort of transfer.

1. Create a set of tables in your destination database that have the same table schemas as the tables in your source system.

   - I typically put these into their own database schema so their purpose is clear.
   - I also typically use the SSIS OLE DB Destination package's "New" button to create the tables.
   - Mind the square brackets on [Schema].[TableName] when editing the CREATE TABLE statement it provides.
2. Use SSIS Data Flow tasks to pull the data from the source to the replica tables in the destination.

   - This can be one package or many, depending on how many tables you're pulling over.
3. Create stored procedures in your destination database to transform the data into the shape it needs to be in the final tables.

   - Using SSIS data transformations is, almost without exception, less efficient than using server side SQL processing.
4. Use SSIS Execute SQL tasks to call the stored procedures.

   - Use parallel processing via Sequence Containers where possible to save time.
   - This can be one package or many, depending on how many tables you're transforming.
5. (Optional) If the transformations are complex, requiring intermediate data sets, you may want to create a separate Staging database schema for this step.
6. You will have to decide whether you want to use the stored procedures to land the data in your ultimate destination tables, or if you want to have the procedures write to intermediate tables, and then move the transformed data directly into the final tables. Using intermediate tables minimizes down time on the final tables, but if your transformations are simple or very fast, this may not be an issue for you.

   - If you use intermediate tables, you will need a package or packages to manage the final data load into the destination tables.
7. Depending on the number of packages all of this takes, you may want to create a Master SSIS package that will call the extraction package(s), then the transformation package(s), and then, if you use intermediate processing tables, the final load package(s).

Comment: Thanks for the response . This  helps me to move  further.

Comment: You're welcome. "Thank you"s are nice, and I do appreciate them, but up votes are better. (And I think Matt's answer deserves one, too) They tell other users that the answer is worth reading, which is useful when they're this long. Good luck on your project.

Comment: Eric, If Destination Schema is different from source , what is the best option to handle this using SSIS?

Comment: @Vasu I agree with Eric when you get enough reputation upvotes are great! I follow very similar patterns with my SSIS packages and agree with the statement that stored procedures are way better than SSIS transformations.  I like SSIS for the "plumbing" moving data from A to B but most transformation is done at staging table.  I will many times use my tables both as staging and as transformation tables.  E.g. include extra columns specific to reporting/data warehouse then update that staging table and once transformed bring into final destination table.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about upvotes and rep, @Matt. And Vasu, I agree with Matt on the staging tables. If your schemas are different, then I'd use stored procedures and staging tables in the destination database to manipulate the data as needed. I'd probably use a procedure to put the final data into the dbo layer. I've used data flows in SSIS, too, but usually work inside one database goes faster with code right there on the server.